# commonjs resolver missing ./axios.js specifier in axios package

Tags: reactjs, axios, vite

I built a react project using vite. In the project I use the axios library to make api calls. In development, I am able to use axios with no issues from vite.

When I run the npm run build command I get this error from vite [commonjs--resolver] Missing "./axios.js" specifier in "axios" package
error during build:
Error: Missing "./axios.js" specifier in "axios" package.

I tried to use the define object in my vite config file but the error persisted. I import axios in my component with "import axios from "axios".I tried to use "import axios from "axios/lib/axios.js" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error by deleting my node_modules folder and installing it again. I also defined global in my vite.config file per the instructions [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/discussions/5879#discussioncomment-6913802)